# How to get Mac's Cmd key working on a Linux

Tags: linux, mac, keyboard-shortcuts

I want to be able to, like on Mac, get my Linux to be able to send an additional key event on top of Ctrl, that is, the Cmd key event. And then easily map keybindings on Linux to listen for that Cmd key event, ending up with the same shortcuts you get on a mac (<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> copies, <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> closes window, etc)

I'd map a standard keyboard's <kbd>Alt</kbd> to Cmd, and the <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> (as that's how my Mac's setup, so I can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> as <kbd>Esc</kbd> on the terminal).

Is this possible? And more importantly, are there easy solutions/setups for getting this?
Note: I DON'T want to run Linux on a Mac machine, I want to run Linux on a PC machine, with a normal keyboard, and have it behave like a mac in terms of keys.

Answer (score 2):

Checkout my project Kinto. It won’t setup caps lock as Ctrl, but it does remap things so that functionally Linux will have macOS like keybinds.

You can certainly play w/ the stock setxkbcomp options & find what you’d need for caps to be control & the modify my custom ~/.xkb/keymap/ files to reflect that option easily enough though.

https://www.github.com/rbreaves/kinto